# Many to Many relationship display

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have a many to many relationship between two tables (Reservations 1..n - 1..n Rooms). 
[image]

From a combo box you should be able to pick a reservation - solved using an Adapter. 
In a data grid, all the content of the Rooms table should be displayed (-solved using an Adapter) and a new column must be added(the rightmost column from the image ), a check box, which will be checked if that room is on the reservation selected in the combo box .

There's how my form looks like:
[image]

How can i check only those which are on the selected reservation?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't look much like an ASP.NET grid.

Comment: Datasets, Entity Framework, other ?

Comment: It's a windows forms application, .net framework 4.5
which has access a SQL server 2008
(if I got right the question)

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant but try this: after you select a rezervation from list, fill a new datatable with the rooms in that reservation

`Select RNumber from ReservationDetails where rID =` .... the selected rezervation id

And after that with two for loops you should be able to check the combobox in the grid